# How to create uniform dashes in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I want to make a bunch of dashes that are 10 pixels long horizontally, 5 pixels long vertically, and separated by 20 pixels. Is there any way to do this easily in GIMP?

I was looking at slice, but that seems to output the image into a bunch of files. **I just want to be able to make a uniform dash without having to manually draw a line pixel by pixel.**

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a new layer with a width of 10px and a transparent background.

   [image]
2. Select your new layer and use the Grid rendering tool (*Filters->Render->Pattern->Grid...*).
   I used these settings:
   [image]

   Pay particular attention to the Horizontal Lines width of 5, and Spacing of 20. Making the vertical line width 0 keeps them from being drawn so vertical line spacing doesn't matter.  Offset was also arbitrary.
3. Take your layer and drag it where you want in your image.

   [image]

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to GD.SE :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to write an "N" hyphen is simply to type an underscore _ and change the baseline of that text in the floating text box tool when you click on a text layer.